# Mysql update a row with another row value in same table

Tags: mysql

I have a table.  I want to update the 5th row with 10th row values from the same table.  For example:

```
SlNo   Name Quali   Exp
1        x   B.E     2
2        y   BSC     3
3        Z   B.A     1.5
4        A   MSC     2
5        B   MBA     5
```

Here i want to update second row with the value of 5th row.

Here is my current query:

```
    UPDATE table 
      SET Name=(select Name from table where slNo='5'),
               Quali=(select Quali from  table where slNo='5'),
               Exp=(select Exp from table where slNo='5') 
      where slNo='3';
```

this is working fine ... but if there are more than 20 columns it becomes laborious to write a query this way, because for each column I have to include another sub-query... is there any other way to write query to update the whole row with all values from the other row in the same table?

Comment: I you provide the reason why you want to update the row 2 with row 5 it would help solve your problem.

Answer (score 31):

Use a self-join with the multiple table `UPDATE` syntax:

```sql
UPDATE `table` AS t1 JOIN `table` AS t2 ON t2.slNo = 5
SET    t1.Name = t2.Name, t1.Quali = t2.Quali, t1.Exp = t2.Exp
WHERE  t1.slNo = 3
```

Comment: ok this is fine... but if the table column is morethan 25... we need to write all 25 columns know ?

Comment: @Dhinesh.B: You're looking for the update-all-columns-but-one syntax? I have a feeling what you really need is another column with a sort value to use for ordering, rather than updating a bunch of stuff.

Comment: it didn't work for me. UPDATE `user` AS u1 JOIN `user` AS u2 ON u2.user_id = 1
SET    u1.password = u2.password, u1.salt = u2.salt
WHERE  u1.user_id = 64