# copy (with update) certain content from the same table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I wanted to UPDATE the value of my below table (row & col_md) :

[Current Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWOtc.png)

```
| id  | id_cat | row  | col_md |
| --- | ------ | ---- | ------ |
| 1   | 1      | 1    | 4      |
| 2   | 1      | 2    | 5      |
| 3   | 1      | 3    | 5      |
| 4   | 2      | 1    | 3      |
| 5   | 2      | 2    | 4      |
| 6   | 2      | 2    | 4      |
| 7   | 3      | 1    | 12     |
| 8   | 3      | 1    | 12     |
| 9   | 3      | 2    | 3      |
```

That may look something like the below table. (I want to have the same content of rows that id_cat=1 have, in rows with id_cat=2 & 3).

[Required Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnmqL.png):

```
| id  | id_cat | row  | col_md |
| --- | ------ | ---- | ------ |
| 1   | 1      | 1    | 4      |
| 2   | 1      | 2    | 5      |
| 3   | 1      | 3    | 5      |
| 4   | 2      | 1    | 4      |
| 5   | 2      | 2    | 5      |
| 6   | 2      | 3    | 5      |
| 7   | 3      | 1    | 4      |
| 8   | 3      | 2    | 5      |
| 9   | 3      | 3    | 5      |
```

id_cat 2 and 3 should have the same "row" and "col_md" values as in id_cat=1.

I've tried with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10895646/mysql-update-a-row-with-another-row-value-in-same-table) post first answer like this:

```
UPDATE `myTable` AS t1 JOIN `myTable` AS t2 ON t2.id_cat=1
SET    t1.row = t2.row, t1.col_md = t2.col_md
WHERE  t1.id_cat = 2 or t1.id_cat=3;
```

but that results on all "row" column values equal to 1.

What I'm doing wrong and what's the way to do this right?

**EDIT:**

**The tables above are just examples to make this ask easier to understand, but the real table is bigger (4k rows) and:**

- "row" column with id_cat=1 can have any number and not a sequence as in the example.
- "col_md" columns can have any number too.
- That's why the update must set a copy of the id_cat=1 "row" and "col_md" values in the id_cat!=1 "row" and "col_md" values.

If this can't be done with just MySQL, a **php** script will be nice too.

Comment: Let me understand this, you want id_cat 1 to have 1,2,3 rows then the next id_cat to have the same row value too? So, id_cat 2 will also have 1,2,3 rows and so on?

Comment: @tcadidot0 htat's right, english is not my native language, so if you can suggest an eddit, I'll take it.

Comment: how many distinct id_cat should you update? Only 2 (2 and 3) or are there more of them? Also, you say "copy (with update) and that is confusing: does your other id_cat rows exists (which would result in UPDATE only), or do you need to create them (INSERT)

Comment: @ThomasG not insert, just update.

Comment: @RobertoSepúlvedaBravo: which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @GMB I'm using MySQL version 5.7

Comment: Instead of Updating table, alternate approach could be to Insert the required record into a new table. This can be achieved as follow
1. Create a tmp table with same fileds (id Auto_Increment, id_cat, row, col_md)
2. Insert to tmp table with this statement...
INSERT INTO tmp(id_cat, row, col_md) 
SELECT t2.id_cat, t1.row, t1.col_md 
 FROM (SELECT row, col_md from mytable WHERE id_cat=1) as t1 , mytable as t2 
 GROUP BY t2.id_cat, t1.row, t1.col_md
3. Remove/Rename 'myTable'
4. Rename 'tmp' table to 'myTable'.

Comment: @KamranFeroz what you say is probably the way that I'm going to do this if there's not an update way. It's just that the id is being referenced on another table, I'll have to check how to remove that referenced table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not enough to tell which group you want the data from, you need to match id to id.

in your case `t2.id` **4** and **7** to `t1.id` **1**, `t2.id` **5** and **8** to `t1.id` **2**, and `t2.id` **6** and **9** to `t1.id` **3**.

```
SELECT @d := COUNT(*) FROM myTable WHERE id_cat = 1;

UPDATE `myTable` AS t1 
JOIN `myTable` AS t2 ON t2.id_cat=1 AND 
t2.id = IFNULL(NULLIF(t1.id MOD @d, 0), @d)
SET    t1.row = t2.row, t1.col_md = t2.col_md
WHERE  t1.id_cat = 2 or t1.id_cat=3;
```

`@d` holds the number of lines where id_cat = 1

we divide `t1.id` by `@d` and match the remainder (`MOD`) to `t2.id`.

when `t1.id` is multiple of `@d` the remainder is `0` and we have to match it to `@d`

so we make `0` into `NULL` and `NULL` into `@d`

Comment: @RobertoSepúlvedaBravo i modified my answer

Comment: An awesome solution! You've made me the day. Thanks too much.

Comment: @RobertoSepúlvedaBravo this code only updates the lines, doesn't add any. so, if the line count is not multiple of the number of `id_cat = 1` lines, the series will be incomplete. (if you didn't have line 9 in the example, those values would be missing)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, the original table was updated perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

In the example query you gave, you are updating t1.row with t2.row. As you are joining on the id_cat, this will result in multiple rows selected to update a single row, so the outcome just takes the first row.

What you actually want, is to make the 1-to-1 relation in the update, so what needs to be changed in your query is to add the row matching in the join and remove the assignment in the SET, like this:

```
UPDATE `myTable` AS t1 JOIN `myTable` AS t2 ON t2.id_cat=1 AND t1.row = t2.row
SET t1.col_md = t2.col_md
WHERE  t1.id_cat = 2 or t1.id_cat=3;
```

Which then gives the output of:

```
MariaDB [testart]> select * from myTable;
+------+--------+------+--------+
| id   | id_cat | row  | col_md |
+------+--------+------+--------+
|    1 |      1 |    1 |      4 |
|    2 |      1 |    2 |      5 |
|    3 |      1 |    3 |      5 |
|    4 |      2 |    1 |      4 |
|    5 |      2 |    2 |      5 |
|    6 |      2 |    3 |      5 |
|    7 |      3 |    1 |      4 |
|    8 |      3 |    1 |      4 |
|    9 |      3 |    2 |      5 |
+------+--------+------+--------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: This UPDATE statement will result in all the 'row' with value 1 and all 'col_md' as value 4 (except 'id_cat'=1).

Comment: This looks fine to me.. did you actually test it @KamranFeroz?

Comment: I only wrote my own answer because the comments said this didn't work, and ended up almost duplicating this one.. but it includes an intermediate query so I will leave it for now

Comment: @Arth Yes I test it on the provided data (in the first table).

Comment: @KamranFeroz, so did I and it gave the results that Art published!

Comment: @Arth, the query didn't serve the purpose. The initial requirement was to update row and col_md both fields with the data-set as in id_cat=1... The requirement was to to have 1-4, 2-5 & 3-5 in row-col_md for id_cat 2 & 3.
The same is confirmed by Roberto (yep, this doesn't work at all. – Roberto Sepúlveda Bravo). Kindly do check the initial query again and retest the Update. I'm open to learn how this works...

Comment: @KamranFeroz, yep.. it works as advertised, see [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oTxm3H6ADen2GVRJjG9MP8/1) adapted from fiddle in answer by GMB

Comment: @KamranFeroz, ah, my apologies.. I wasn't aware the rows needed updating too. I thought we were merging the col_md values into the rows

Comment: +1 on the rows needing update as well. If I had known that, I would probably suggested using a temporary table instead

Answer (score 2):

Currently able to achieve the SQL query for your desired result.

```html
SELECT t2.id_cat, t1.row, t1.col_md 
FROM (SELECT row, col_md from mytable WHERE id_cat=1) as t1 , mytable as t2 
GROUP BY t2.id_cat, t1.row, t1.col_md
```

The above will return the following..

[image]

I suggest to use INSERT statement along with the above query to put the record into a new table and drop the old one.

Cheers!

**EDITED...**

Instead of Updating table, alternate approach could be to Insert the required record into a new table. 
This can be achieved with following four steps

1. Create a tmp table with same fileds (id Auto_Increment, id_cat, row, col_md)
2. Insert to tmp table with this statement...

```html
INSERT INTO tmp(id_cat, row, col_md) 
SELECT t2.id_cat, t1.row, t1.col_md 
 FROM (SELECT row, col_md from mytable WHERE id_cat=1) as t1 , mytable as t2 
 GROUP BY t2.id_cat, t1.row, t1.col_md
```

4. Remove/Rename 'myTable'.
5. Rename 'tmp' table to 'myTable'.

Hope this will serve the purpose...

Cheers!

Comment: Not able to get the required result with the update query. I believe it will be easy to achieve it with INSERT.

Comment: I'm now convinced this is a more sensible approach to this problem than update, as targeting duplicate rows and updating them with different information is very complex. From the clarification to the original question, it feels like this will be a one off migration.. otherwise I think the problem is much deeper.

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding, the difficult part about this question is to relate each record to update (ie each record with `id_cat IN (2, 3)`) to the relevant original record (record with `id_cat = 1`).

Based on your sample data, I understand that you expect *series* of records for each `id_cat` (I can see three groups of three records, sorted by increasing `id`), so I would assume that you want to relate each record to the original that has the *same sequence* in the group of record where `id_cat = 1`.

Assuming MySQL 8.0, a typical approach to assign a number to a record within a group is `ROW_NUMBER()`. Consider this simple query:

```
SELECT 
    t.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id_cat ORDER BY id) rn
FROM t
```

Yields:

```
| id  | id_cat | rw  | col_md | rn  |
| --- | ------ | --- | ------ | --- |
| 1   | 1      | 1   | 4      | 1   |
| 2   | 1      | 2   | 5      | 2   |
| 3   | 1      | 3   | 5      | 3   |
| 4   | 2      | 1   | 3      | 1   |
| 5   | 2      | 2   | 4      | 2   |
| 6   | 2      | 2   | 4      | 3   |
| 7   | 3      | 1   | 12     | 1   |
| 8   | 3      | 1   | 12     | 2   |
| 9   | 3      | 2   | 3      | 3   |
```

Now with this set-up in mind, we can turn this query to a Common Table Expression (available also starting MySQL 8.0), and `JOIN` it as need with the original table to do the `UPDATE`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        t.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id_cat ORDER BY id) rn
    FROM t
)
UPDATE t t0
INNER JOIN cte t1 ON t1.id = t0.id
INNER JOIN cte t2 ON t2.id_cat = 1 AND t2.rn = t1.rn
SET t0.rw = t2.rw, t0.col_md = t2.col_md
WHERE t0.id_cat IN (2, 3)
```

Details:

- `t0` is the original table, where records having `id_cat IN (2, 3)` need to be updated
- `t1` is the corresponding record in the CTE (to which a row number was assigned)
- `t2` is the record in the CTE that has `id_cat = 1` and the same row number as the record being updated

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oTxm3H6ADen2GVRJjG9MP8/0)**:

```
| id  | id_cat | rw  | col_md |
| --- | ------ | --- | ------ |
| 1   | 1      | 1   | 4      |
| 2   | 1      | 2   | 5      |
| 3   | 1      | 3   | 5      |
| 4   | 2      | 1   | 4      |
| 5   | 2      | 2   | 5      |
| 6   | 2      | 3   | 5      |
| 7   | 3      | 1   | 4      |
| 8   | 3      | 2   | 5      |
| 9   | 3      | 3   | 5      |
```

Comment: I'm not trying to follow an incremental sequence in the 'row' column, I've tryed your first query like this: `SELECT 
        myTable.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id_cat ORDER BY id) rn
    FROM myTable`  but it throws syntax error near  '(PARTITION BY id_cat ORDER BY id) rn
    FROM myTable LIMIT 0, 25' at line 3

Comment: That sequence in the 'row' column is just coincidende, it could be any number.